# Add Name Value pair to existing particular Key in Firebase Realtime Database (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database structure as Firebase Database structure] as shown in the image.

[image]

I want to add a new name value to particular key.

For example I want to add an array of "Posts" name and the values of the "Posts" name to be entered from textfield .

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: What is the problem? What is keeping you from adding this `Posts` node?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I want to add the Posts name value pair to the key -MHQsnaQzllNlPe_4oYT. and that posts name will contain and array of string values.

Comment: I get what you're trying to do, but I'm not sure what problem you're having doing that. You're most likely to get help here on Stack Overflow if you show what you've tried, and where you got stuck. There's an `edit` link under your question to add such information. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).